# Android Camera: fixed lens focus

Tags: android, android-camera, autofocus

I'm developing an Android application with a camera-related functionality feature.

First of all, I read a lot of stuff on SO, XDA and so on, then please don't redirect me to other useless posts.

I am trying to implement something like a "fixed focus mode", so that:

1. I start my application with `FOCUS_MODE_AUTO` (or something else);
2. bring into focus an object at an arbitrary distance;
3. fix the current focus;
4. move the camera on another object at a different distance which is out of focus.

I tried different solutions, i.e.:

- `mCamera.cancelAutoFocus()` in the `AutoFocusCallback` to prevent the adjustment of the focus;
- set a `FocusArea`: `new Camera.Area(new Rect(-50, -50, 50, 50), 1000)` to fix the focus on the current area.

I'm targeting API 20 and I'm working on a Samsung Galaxy S5. On this device, the supported focus modes are:
- auto
- infinity
- macro
- continuous-video
- continuous-picture

The suggestion that I found more frequently is to recompile Android...

Comment: You want tap to focus? and can you post some code of surfaceview class?

Comment: Hi. I added a button above the preview that, ideally, has to switch from auto focus mode to "fixed focus" mode and vice versa. There isn't anything interesting in my code, simply I don't know how to do it or even if it is possible.

Comment: How are you performing the focus? "AUTO" mode doesn't mean that the camera continuously focuses - just that when you call  the autoFocus command the focus is done automatically with no indication on what result you expect not like "Macro" or "Infinity".   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#autoFocus(android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback) 
So if you don't have a loop that calls the autoFocus (as many examples do or call it again in the Callback) your focus should stay after it runs once.

Comment: @Raanan is right - auto focus should do exactly what you need in this case. Calling cancelAutoFocus() actually forces the camera to re-focus in the devices I've worked with.

Comment: I have just changed my code according to your comments. I launch the camera in FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE and then change mode to FOCUS_MODE_AUTO (using a dedicated onscreen button). It seems to be working just fine.

Comment: I added my comment as an Answer. Happy that it worked.

Answer (score 2):

"AUTO" mode doesn't mean that the camera continuously focuses - just that when you call the autoFocus command the focus is done automatically with no indication on what result you expect not like "Macro" or "Infinity".

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#autoFocus(android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback)

So if you don't have a loop that calls the autoFocus (as many examples do or call it again in the Callback) your focus should stay after it runs once.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand, you want to focus keep the focus of the first object.
Have you tried to change the camera mode to `FOCUS_MODE_FIXED` after you focus the first object ?
Like that :

```
Camera.Parameters mParam = mCamera.getParameters();
mParam.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_FIXED);
mCamera.setParameters(mParam);
```

Comment: Hi Alonso, unfortunately the target devices for my application (S4 and S5) don't support FOCUS_MODE_FIXED. However, this mode doesn't fix it to the current focus but to a hyperfocal distance.